# Does ESXi host running on 7th gen Intel processor support Win 7 and older OSes?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-esxi, vmware-server

I know that Windows 7 and older OSes are not supported on the newest Intel i series processors.
But how about an OS running on a ESXi host?
Is it going to work this way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You mean if the Windows 7 VM will be on ESXi host? Yes it will work, cause you're assigning an amount of vCPUs on a VM.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. To sum - virtualized hardware from vmware is not directly connected with a physical processor limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know if this is going to *work* or if it's *supported*?

I should think if your OS isn't supported on 7th gen Intel processors it's not supported, no matter if you have a hypervisor underneath or not. But this depends, like everything that involves "supported", ultimately on the OS vendor.

If it's going to work will probably depend on your OS. In contrast to an emulator, a VM on a hypervisor runs directly on the CPU. So if your OS checks the CPU model and stops working if it's "too new", ESXi won't help you there. As far as I know there is no way to show a 7th gen Intel processor as 6th gen to a VM.

To make a long story short: If you want to know if it works, test it. If you want to know if it's supported, ask your OS vendor.